# Is it possible to install RubyGems on Ruby 1.8.6?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install RubyGems on a Fedora-based distribution that only has Ruby 1.8.6. I downloaded the RubyGems 1.6.2 package, unzipped and ran

```
$ ruby setup.rb
```

It bombs out with the rather unhelpful error message:

```
./lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
./lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:in `require': undefined method `end_with?' for "no such file to load -- Win32API":String (NoMethod\
Error)
   from ./lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:55
   from ./lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
   from ./lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
   from ./lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:8
   from ./lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
   from ./lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
   from setup.rb:25
```

Looking at the source of the exception, it seems that it first tries:

```
require "etc"
Etc.sysconfdir
```

and when that throws a `NoMethodError` it tries to require `Win32API` (which I assume isn't present on linux).

I'm guessing that this could be because I have an old version of Ruby, but I can't find the RubyGems version requirements documented anywhere. Can anyone suggest how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible to install RubyGems on Ruby 1.8.6, but not RubyGems 1.6.2. Support for Ruby 1.8.6 was dropped in RubyGems 1.4.0.

Why are you trying to circumvent your Linux distribution's package manager? They test interoperability between the packages they ship *precisely* to avoid situations like this.

In general, it is not a good idea to mix different package management systems. Ideally, you shouldn't be using RubyGems at all, when using Linux, since most distribution's package management systems are as good as RubyGems anyway. RubyGems is only needed on operating systems like Windows or OSX which are still stuck in the 1980s.

Thats what I do on my Redmine installation, for example: I just use the distribution packages of Rails, RedCloth, RMagick, Rack, Redmine, Ruby Enterprise Edition, Phusion Passenger, and whatever else I need. I don't even have RubyGems installed *at all*, neither from a distribution package nor from source.

If, however, for some reason, you *need* RubyGems, then you should move your entire Ruby environment out of the distribution package manager and manage it yourself. Just install whatever version and flavor of Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, YARV or whatever you want, install the latest version of RubyGems from source (or don't, since all of the above already ship with one pre-installed anyway) and install all of your Ruby libraries as Gems.

As was noted in other answers, RVM can be of help, but is generally unnecessary unless you want to manage multiple Ruby installations on the same machine.

Comment: I couldn't find a version of rubygems for my distribution. I'm not actually using Fedora, but a modified distribution based on it, and I don't believe all the standard packages are available. Either that or I'm not passing the right magic args to yum.

Comment: I agree with you. RVM might be unnecessary if you don't need to install multiple Ruby environments. But even if you use only one Ruby version and need to use rubygems, the RVM can help keeping things organized using [named gem sets](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/). And the installation of interpreters (MRI, Rubinus, JRuby, etc) is pretty straightforward. That may be an important thing to consider if you don't want to build things from source (RVM downloads, builds, installs and manages the rubies for you).

Comment: What? It has nothing to do with linux package managers being "better" than rubygems. They do completely different jobs. Apt, yum and friends are designed to install what the system currently designates "the" stable version. Rubygems is designed to manage multiple versions of the same gem at once. When you install a gem dependency of (say) a rails app, you don't want "the stable version" -- you want the exact version the app was developed against. (That's what bundler is for.) To say one is "better" is to misunderstand their complementary purposes.

Comment: The purpose of Rubygems is to be able to package Ruby libraries for others to use easily; it's not even on the same plane as Yum or Apt. Many Rubygems are just not available as packages for systems since that's not what they're intended.

Answer (score 1):

How about installing [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)? Then you can manage multiple Ruby versions easily and, maybe, install a more recent version of Ruby. It works really well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install RubyGems greater than 1.3.5 if you only have Ruby version 1.8.5.
RubyGems requires at least Ruby 1.8.6 to install.

My background:
 - I have RubyGems 1.3.5 installed in
   my CentOS Linux because Ruby is 1.8.6.
 - What I did with Mac OS X, which comes
   with Ruby 1.8.7, is to upgrade gem
   from version 1.3.5 to version 1.6.2
   by using the original gem.